# Bounded-buffer using java library semaphore

Tags: java, semaphore

i currently have an assignment where i'm supposed to make a semaphore for the bounded buffer problem. I think my first code is ok and should work (if i understand semaphores right, which i'm not sure about btw)

The second part of the assigment is to use java library to implement semaphores. Have i done this right? 
I have provided both code blocks for each part of the assignment. i just need a verification if my code is correct and maybe some input about the use of java semaphore library :)

```
semaphore mutex = 1;
semaphore fillCount = 0;
semaphore emptyCount = BUFFER_SIZE;

procedure producer() {
  while (true) {
    item = produceItem();       
    down(emptyCount);       
        down(mutex);            
            putItemIntoBuffer(item);    
        up(mutex);          
    up(fillCount);      
}
}

procedure consumer() {
while (true) {
    down(fillCount);                
        down(mutex);                
            item = removeItemFromBuffer();  
        up(mutex);              
    up(emptyCount);             
    consumeItem(item);      
}
}
```

With Java-Semaphore:

```
 Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

public producer(){     

semaphore.acquire();  
    putItemIntoBuffer(item);  
semaphore.release(); 

}

public consumer(){
semaphore.acquire();

removeItemFromBuffer(item);   

semaphore.release();
 }
```

Comment: Fine, though the java part misses things maybe? **One issue**: the semaphore there is for the mutual exclusion. If inside one of putItemIntoBuffer/removeItemFromBuffer it blocks, because of waiting on not-full/not-empty there is **dead-lock**: The counter-part will block on the mutex semaphore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code example you use a binary semaphore and a counting semaphore. You should use that in your java implementation as well.
I think, that you should initialize the semaphore (which is used for the product count) with 0. 
When you use 1 you can take an item from your buffer, when it is still empty.

```
Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);
Semaphore productCount = new Semaphre(0);

public producer(){     

mutex.acquire();  //entering critical section
    putItemIntoBuffer(item); //produce your item in the exclusive mode
    productCount.release();  //increase your product count
mutex.release();  //leave critical section

}

public consumer(){
mutex.acquire(); //entering critical section

if(productCount.availablePermits() > 0) //test if you have already poduced some items
{
   removeItemFromBuffer(item); //remove your item in the exclusive mode  
   productCount.acquire();     //decrease your item count
}

mutex.release(); //leave critical section
 }
```

Comment: Okey! Thanks. Helped a lot - i understand the usage of semaphore a bit better now.

Answer (score 0):

using lock and Condition objects

```
class BoundedBuffer {
   final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
   final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition(); 

   final Object[] items = new Object[100];
   int putptr, takeptr, count;

   public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == items.length)
         notFull.await();
       items[putptr] = x;
       if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
       ++count;
       notEmpty.signal();
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public Object take() throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == 0)
         notEmpty.await();
       Object x = items[takeptr];
       if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
       --count;
       notFull.signal();
       return x;
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }
 }
```